# If/else if: pick first matching record within set distance only after first condition is not met in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, distance, euclidean-distance

I would like to pick the closest previous owner within a set distance only after the first search condition isn't met. The locations are called `reflo` (reference location), and they have a corresponding x and y coordinates (called `locx` and `locy`, respectively).

**The conditions:**

- if `lifetime_census$reflo==owners$reflo.x[i]` then condition is met
- if `lifetime_census$reflo!=owners$reflo.x[i]`, then find next closest record (within 30 meters)
- if there is no record within 30 meters, then assign `NA`

Previous owners (>20,000) are stored in a dataset called `lifetime_census`. Here is a sample of the data:

```
id         previous_id  reflo  locx    locy   lifespan  
16161      5587         -310    -3     10     1810    
16848      5101         Q1      17.3   0.8    55    
21815      6077         M2      13     1.8    979
23938      6130         -49     -4     9      374
29615      7307         B.1     2.5    1      1130
```

I then have an `owners` dataset (here is a sample):

```
squirrel_id      spr_census reflo.x    spring_locx      spring_locy 
6391              2005       M3           13             2.5  
6130              2005       -310         -3             10    
23586             2019       B9           2              9
```

**To illustrate what I am trying to achieve:**

```
squirrel_id spr_census reflo.x spring_locx spring_locy previous_owner   
6391        2004       M3       13         2.5         6077            
6130        2005       -310     -3         10          5587   
23586       2019       B9       2          9           NA
```

What I have currently tried is this:

```
n <- length(owners$squirrel_id)
distance <- 30 #This can be easily changed to bigger or smaller values

for(i in 1:n) {
  last_owner <- subset(lifetime_census,
    lifetime_census$reflo==owners$reflo.x[i] & #using the exact location
((30*owners$spring_locx[i]-30* lifetime_census$locx)^2+(30* owners$spring_locy[i]-30* lifetime_census$locy)^2<=(distance)^2)) #this sets the search limit

owners[i,"previous_owner"] <- last_owner$previous_id[i]

}
```

**I cannot figure out how to have the loop go through the conditions in order and then select the record within the search limit only after no exact match was found.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is there a factor of 30 in the distance calculation here: `(30*owners$spring_locx[i]-30* lifetime_census$locx)^2`

Comment: Also, does same `reflo` always imply same xy coordinates?

Comment: The factor of 30 is because 1 unit is 30 meters, so this is the conversion unit. What do you mean for your second question? If I understand it correctly, then no - the `reflo` does not always have the same xy coordinates. For example, `reflo` "Q1" could have a `locx` that is around 17 (so, realistically between 16.5 and 17.5) and a `locy` that is around 1 (0.5-1.5).

Comment: According to your example, M4 and M2 should be too far apart. Also, what happens in case of duplicate reflo's?

Comment: I'll fix that (I was making up the example because I don't have code that actually runs). There are no duplicate reflos within years (think of reflos like postal addresses). For example, in 2004 there would be only one M4, only one M2, only one M3, etc. But, these same reflos would be repeated in other years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this (asumming the units for `locx` and alike are the same as for `distance`:

```
distance = 30

distance_xy = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 -y1)^2)
}

for (i in 1:dim(owners)[1]) {
  if (owners$reflo.x[i] %in% lifetime_census$reflo) {
    owners$previous_owner[i] = lifetime_census[lifetime_census$reflo == owners$reflo.x[i], ]$previous_id
  } else {
    dt = distance_xy(owners$spring_locx[i], owners$spring_locy[i], lifetime_census$locx, lifetime_census$locy)
      if (any(dt <= distance)) {
        owners$previous_owner[i] = lifetime_census[order(dt), ]$previous_id[1L]
      } else {
        owners$previous_id[i] = NA
      }
    }
  }
```

which gives:

```
   squirrel_id spr_census reflo.x spring_locx spring_locy previous_owner
1        6391       2005      M3          13         2.5           6077
2        6130       2005    -310          -3        10.0           5587
3       23586       2019      B9           2         9.0           5587
```

Note that this will fail if there are more than one match for `reflo`.

[EDIT] Adding an alternative based on comment below.

`if`-`else` statements can get pretty confusing when you start adding conditions. This is another way of achieving the same while avoiding the nested structure above:

```
for (i in 1:dim(owners)[1]) {

  # if we find the reflo
  if (owners$reflo.x[i] %in% lifetime_census$reflo) {
    owners$previous_owner[i] = lifetime_census[lifetime_census$reflo == owners$reflo.x[i], ]$previous_id
    next
  }

  # if we got here, then we didn't find the reflo, compute distances:
  dt = distance_xy(owners$spring_locx[i], owners$spring_locy[i], lifetime_census$locx, lifetime_census$locy)

  # if we find anyone within distance, get the closest one
  if (any(dt <= distance)) {
    owners$previous_owner[i] = lifetime_census[order(dt), ]$previous_id[1L]
    next
  }

  # if we got here, there was nobody within range, set NA and move on:
  owners$previous_id[i] = NA
}
```

The code does exactly the same, but by taking advantage of the `for` loop and `next` it is possible to remove every `else` and the hole nested structure.

Comment: I don't think your solution is working the way it is supposed to? The only 1 squirrel_id` row with a `previous_owner` is the only one that should not have one. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are absolutely right, the loop range was wrong, changed it from `i in dim(owners)[1]` to `i in 1:dim(owners)[1]`. Note i am not using the 30x factor. Also, if you like the solution, i would still suggest to explore alternatives using `apply` functions or one of the packages suggested by other answers since this loop i propose is easy to read but maybe slow to run on >20.000 records...

Comment: Thanks for that edit. I struggle a lot with writing coherent if/else statements. Could you edit your answer to show me how to add either an additional condition? Like to say if `lifetime_census$previous_id != owners$squirrel_id[i]` & the reflo condition, else...

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist i don't understand that last condition... I am adding an edit with an alternative to make the conditional sequence more readable.

Comment: Sorry! So what I mean is that the previous owner `previous_id` cannot be the same as the current owner `squirrel_id`. This is one of many conditions I need to add, so I think I can figure out how to format it with your new edits, but will the code allow for multiple conditions inside the first `if` statement? (like if reflo==reflo & previous_id != squirrel_id)

Comment: Sure, as long as the expression within `if ()` evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` things will keep working. Just be careful with `&` and `&&` operands, the first could return a vector of `length() > 1` while the second always returns a single value.

Comment: I can't seem to add any of the conditions I want to. I am having no luck in getting the notation right. I've posted this as a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625882/multiple-conditions-for-if-else-statement-in-r

Comment: Hi there @BlunderingEcologist, i think you would make a lot from figuring out how to code this by yourself. I suggest you play around concatenating conditions until you feel comfortable. Then, as ilustrated by @Rohit, the `dplyr` package is tailored to do this sort of *data wrangling*, and it's really great at it. [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/), by Hadley Wickman, has everything you need to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 2 sets of criteria, I suggest splitting the task into two parts as well. Also, when combining two dataframes, I always suggest finding a suitable join.

For the exact matches, `dplyr::inner_join` will give you the right rows.

For the next part, you can exclude the exact matches and use `distance_left_join` from the `fuzzyjoin` package to match the remaining rows. It comes with an option for maximum distance as well.

Then, you can simply bind the two results

```r
library(data.table)
lifetime_census <- fread('id         previous_id  reflo  locx    locy   lifespan  
16161      5587         -310    -3     10     1810    
16848      5101         Q1      17.3   0.8    55    
21815      6077         M2      13     1.8    979
23938      6130         -49     -4     9      374
29615      7307         B.1     3      1      1130')
lifetime_census
#>       id previous_id reflo locx locy lifespan
#> 1: 16161        5587  -310 -3.0 10.0     1810
#> 2: 16848        5101    Q1 17.3  0.8       55
#> 3: 21815        6077    M2 13.0  1.8      979
#> 4: 23938        6130   -49 -4.0  9.0      374
#> 5: 29615        7307   B.1  3.0  1.0     1130
owners <- fread('squirrel_id      spr_census reflo.x    spring_locx      spring_locy 
6391              2005       M3           13             2.5  
6130              2005       -310         -3             10    
23586             2019       B9           2              9')
owners
#>    squirrel_id spr_census reflo.x spring_locx spring_locy
#> 1:        6391       2005      M3          13         2.5
#> 2:        6130       2005    -310          -3        10.0
#> 3:       23586       2019      B9           2         9.0

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:data.table':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(fuzzyjoin)

# Search for exact match
df1 <- inner_join(owners,lifetime_census ,by=c(reflo.x='reflo')) %>% 
  select(squirrel_id:spring_locy,previous_id)
df1
#>   squirrel_id spr_census reflo.x spring_locx spring_locy previous_id
#> 1        6130       2005    -310          -3          10        5587


df2 <- 
  owners %>% 
  anti_join(df1,by=c('squirrel_id')) %>% # Remove rows with exact matches
    distance_left_join(lifetime_census,
                       by=c(spring_locx='locx',spring_locy='locy'), # Match columns
                       max_dist=1, # Since you want a maximum distance of 30m = 1 unit
                       distance_col='dist') %>% # Optional, if you want to see the distance
    select(squirrel_id:spring_locy,previous_id,dist)

bind_rows(df1,df2)  
#>   squirrel_id spr_census reflo.x spring_locx spring_locy previous_id dist
#> 1        6130       2005    -310          -3        10.0        5587   NA
#> 2        6391       2005      M3          13         2.5        6077  0.7
#> 3       23586       2019      B9           2         9.0          NA   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I have a small ask, is there a way to have the distances show for all causes where there is a `previous_id`? (like in the case for `previous_id` 5587).

Comment: The reason I avoided doing an `inner_join` is because the reflo is not the only condition I am working with making the join not flexible enough. Do you know if `fuzzyjoin` is flexible enough for me to adding in additional conditions, such as a condition for only selecting owners from previous years and making sure the `previous_id` does not equal the current `squirrel_id`?

Comment: I posted an updated version of my question with edits to show what I mean/where the problems are coming up because I'm still not quite getting the desired outcome.

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist, I'm not too familiar with `fuzzyjoin` myself since I just found out about it recently, but I think they have an option to specify a match function. Also,  if you remove the `select` operation at the end of the `inner_join`, all the columns are preserved so you can use them to calculate the distance.

Answer (score 1):

The following solves the problem.

Function to calculate distances:

```
distance_xy = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 -y1)^2)
}
```

Determine the previous id within a distance of 30 meters. Set id equal to NA in case all distances are greater than 30 meters.

```
library(tidyverse)

previous_id_fn <- function(v, w, years){
   dists <- map2_dbl(lifetime_census$locx, lifetime_census$locy, ~distance_xy(.x, .y, v, w)) 
   df <- data.frame(previous = lifetime_census$previous_id, 
                    dist = dists, 
                    life = lifetime_census$lifespan) %>% 
               filter(life < years)
   id <- df$previous[[which.min(df$dist)]]
   if (min(df$dist, na.rm = TRUE) > 30) { id <- NA }
   return(id)
}
```

First join data.frame owners with data.frame lifetime_census to obtain a column with previous_id. Then apply the above defined function to each row of the data.frame.

```
owners %>%
  left_join(., lifetime_census, by = c("reflo.x" = "reflo")) %>%
  select(squirrel_id:spring_locy, previous_id) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(previous_id = ifelse(is.na(previous_id), 
                            previous_id_fn(spring_locx, spring_locy, 1000), 
  previous_id))
```

Edit:

I added an argument years to function previous_id_fn(). In case lifespan > years the function now returns NA.

Comment: I think I've gotten your solution nearly working. There is just one glitch that you might have the solution for. In your `previous_id_fn`, it is looking for any previous owner within 30 meters (in any year) - even previous owners from 20 years ago which is a bit over the top. Is there a way to add a limit for the number of years (so something like `lifetime_census$spr_census` <= (2 years) of `owners$spr_census`? Would this be possible by adding another `which.min` condition?

Comment: Also, retaining the other rows (in addition to the `previous_id` would allow me to see how long ago the previous_id was from. This would really help because it would save me from playing the guessing game.

Comment: I posted an updated version of my question with edits to show what I mean/where the problems are coming up.